# Convey that you have an iron will in a cover letter

Tags: word-choice

I am currently helping a friend translating his cover letter, and I would like to know what would be the best word/expression to use to convey that you have an iron will:

> It is equipped with an iron will that I wish to join your company

Here, *equipped* doesn't feel natural at all. Maybe *armed* would be better? Or another expression altogether?

Google searches didn't return a specific colloquial use for it, so I am not sure what to use. Just as a note, the context is a cover letter (so rather stern vocabulary).

Comment: Why use a verb at all? What’s wrong with: _It is with an iron will that I wish to join your company_.

Comment: The company might wonder to what end your **iron will** (or *fierce determination*) was directed. It's not clear whether you are merely very ambitious and determined to work hard or simply inflexible and unlikely to be able to adapt.

Comment: @RonaldSole the company is related to military. Here, the idea to convey is strong determination to work in this field.

Comment: @J.R. I've ended up going with your suggestion. Feel free to write it as an answer so I can close this question.

Comment: This site is about the English language. I would strongly recommend you check on workplace.stackexchange.com whether an “iron will” is something a company is actually looking for in an employee.

Comment: *I would be honoured to become a member of... Nothing would make me prouder than to join your… It is my greatest ambition to be accepted by your…*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like J.R said, I don't think the verb is necessary.

> "It is with an iron will that I wish to join your company."

This flows perfectly.

If you were to use the verb, you could use it almost like this:

> Equipped with my iron will, I wish to join your company.